# Is there a way to broadcast a message into all task managers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

i wonder if there is a way in flink to broadcast an event (or something like that) if specific event read from the source into all the task managers.

To be more specific I am aggregating state data with a map state and if some events are read from the source I want that all task managers perform a specific action

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. The [broadcast state pattern](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html) is meant for exactly this sort of use case.

Answer (score 0):

As David noted, using a broadcast stream is the right way to send data to all (parallel) sub-tasks. As for only broadcasting some data, take a look at [side outputs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) as a way to do special processing for a sub-set of your data. So you could have a `ProcessFunction` that passes through all data un-modified, and if an incoming event is one that wants to be broadcast, then you also emit it as a side output.