# Is there a way to broadcast configuration into all task managers or all FlatMapFunctions?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-statefun

We currently have a flink-based streaming job (the task is composed of complex FlatMapFunctions DAG), and an http interface for fetching configuration.

Now I hope to read configuration from the http interface through a source function every 5 minutes with a parallelism of 1, and then distribute it to all task managers or FlatMapFunctions of the job. In FlatMapFunctions, the configuration will be read and will never not be changed.

I have read the documentation[The Broadcast State Pattern](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/), but the method in the documentation seems to only apply to the first Function of the broadcast, and other subsequent downstream FlatMapFunctions cannot read the state of the broadcast. As shown in the figure below, only `Co-Process-Broadcast` can obtain the broadcast, but `map func 1` and `map func 2` cannot.

Broadcast state graph

[image: 1]

Similar to [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272879/is-there-a-way-to-broadcast-a-message-into-all-task-managers) but different, I have many downstream FlatMapFunctions and expect them all to get the broadcast configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the broadcast stream to multiple functions, so if your config state isn't big then that's likely what I'd do.

If the config state is very small (relative to the size of records being processed) then you could attach it to every incoming record in your `BroadcastProcessFunction`, so downstream operators have it in hand when processing each of their records.